# How can I delete all <div some_attributes="values"> from wp_posts content table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a wordpress site with wp_posts (content) over 1GB data. there are some content with  or only 
I want to delete the Total  tag with those styles and classes.
I tried to use
 `update wp_posts set post_content=replace(post_content, '<div.*?>','')`

but it's not working..

Comment: To clarify: You have HTML in a field called `post_content`. Inside that HTML you want to remove a particular HTML tag like anything between `<div some_attributes="values"> ` and it's closing tag `</div>`, leaving the rest of the HTML for that `post_content` in that record untouched?

Comment: Yes, You are right